# Getting rid of flicker in SWT

Tags: java, swt, progress-bar, double-buffering

We are using a the following class to show a progress-bar in our Java application: [TextProgressBar](http://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/opal/source/browse/src/main/java/org/mihalis/opal/textprogressbar/TextProgressBar.java?spec=svn0392d56b117520d51a97fd211a4da726e25738d8&r=0392d56b117520d51a97fd211a4da726e25738d8)

Unfortunately we are having some problems with flickering when using that (Win 7, Java 7). Do you have any tips on how we can avoid that? Can we somehow repaint it less frequently, use double-buffering or something else? Any tips are greatly appreciated!

Comment: First of all, did you see the note in the Javadoc? "Restriction:
This class is not intended to be subclassed by clients." You should definitely first try `SWT.DOUBLE_BUFFERED`, but there's no guarantees for your case.

Answer (score 6):

First, try passing `SWT.DOUBLE_BUFFERED` in for the style parameter on construction. If that fails to improve the situation, move up the parent chain and add `SWT.DOUBLE_BUFFERED` to their constructor call instead.

If you don't have control over the parent, then you'll likely need to wrap your control in another Composite that has this flag enabled.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but unfortunately it didn't work. I tried adding it to TextProgressBar's constructor and I also tried the parent composite.

Comment: What is triggering the redraws you're seeing? If you can identify an area where it is just being called far too often, you can wrap that with a call to .setRedraw(false) on your control, do the work that causes the rapid redraw normally, then call .setRedraw(true) at the end.

Answer (score 1):

try `SWT.NO_BACKGROUND` first, and if not use `SWT.DOUBLE_BUFFERED`.
Do not use both at the same time, because there is no point.
See the [discussion](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/144393/)

Answer (score 1):

*Disclaimer: I know that the question asks specifically about the `TextProgressBar`. However, I believe that many views of this question are not limited to this widget.*

I had a problem with the flickering of the `Text` widget, which I could not resolve neither by using the `SWT.DOUBLE_BUFFERED` style, nor by wrapping it with the `Composite`, nor by applying any combination of them.

Finally, I was able to resolve this problem by simply changing the widget type from `Text` to `StyledText`. There is no flicker even without the `SWT.DOUBLE_BUFFERED` style and without the `Composite` wrapper.

Hope this will help someone who was attracted by the broad title of this question.

Answer (score -3):

you can try delaying the time with **thread.sleep()**. It worked for me when i had the same problem when working with **jTables**

Comment: Please note that I am talking about SWT. Not Swing.